# Windows Phone 8.1 PDF viewer

Tags: pdf, windows-phone-8, webview, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to create an windows phone 8.1 app in which the user opens a pdf file from a link. Let's say i want to open this pdf file from the link below inside my app at the press of a button, without downloading the file locally.

http://www.analysis.im/uploads/seminar/pdf-sample.pdf

Can this be done with WebView ? The idea is that the user will pass through a list of pdf files stored online and choose one to save locally.

Answer (score 0):

Windows phone 8.1 webview does not support native pdf rendering. 
You can look at [Mozill pdfJS](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/). Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about WebView, but you can render the PDF from the URL natively in the app.

You can created a streamed file, and feed that file to the PDF renderer provided by the Windows.Data.PDF It works fairly well. Check my post [here](https://quirkd.wordpress.com/2015/03/14/rendering-a-pdf-document-from-a-url-winrt/) for a detailed tutorial

```
public PdfDocument Document { get; set; }
public PdfPage CurrentPage { get; set; }
```

Create streamed file -

```
try
{                                                                           
    IRandomAccessStreamReference thumbnail = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri(webURL));
    StorageFile file1 = await StorageFile.CreateStreamedFileFromUriAsync("temp.pdf", new Uri(webURL), thumbnail);
    this.Document = await PdfDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(file1)
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog(ex.Message);
    dialog.ShowAsync();
    return;
}
for (int i = 0; i < Document.PageCount; i++)
{
    await this.RenderPage(i);
}
```

Render the pages -

```
private async Task RenderPage(int index)
{
    this.CurrentPage = this.Document.GetPage((uint)index);
    using (IRandomAccessStream stream = new MemoryStream().AsRandomAccessStream())
    {
        await this.CurrentPage.RenderToStreamAsync(stream);
        BitmapImage source = new BitmapImage();
        source.SetSource(stream);
        Image i = new Image();
        i.Source = source;
        i.Margin = new Thickness(0,5,0,0);
        PagePanel.Children.Add(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Windows.Data.Pdf` namespace is not available under WP8.1